# Configure website in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe

I just started a new contract and I walked into a disaster. There are no other developers and I don't have access to the previous developers.

The website is asp.net in VB, and they use Visual Source Safe 2005 (no I can't change anything. Must work with what I have).

I can get a copy of the current site from VSS and save it locally, but it doesn't behave how I'm used to seeing a project behave in VS 2010. There is no project or solution file, just .aspx pages and .vb files. So... is this the difference between a "web site" and a "web application" as far as VS is concerned? At any rate, how can I set this thing up so I can set break points and debug it? Currently I can't do any of that. Where do I even specify the web server to debug on? I do have access to the production IIS server so would it be easier if I just opened the site from there? Right now I have a bunch of underlined errors for things that are referenced but can't be found. But I downloaded the entire source from VSS so I don't know h ow this can be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try creating a blank web application and copying the pages in individually? Sourcesafe doesn't integrate that well with .NET projects so the .sln file may never have been checked in as I think this would have to have been done manually!

Comment: Tried but not a chance, complete disaster with thousands of errors. There's an App_Code folder with a CSharp folder in it as part of the site so I'm thinking this has to remain a site as opposed to an application.

Comment: Care to tell us what the errors are? There is (most likely) no magic fix for this - you will have to work through the errors one by one, but unless you give us some more information about them we can't help.

Comment: Thanks. Lots of "type or namespace not found," "type not defined," and "unable to update auto-refresh reference," among many, many others.

Comment: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: I think you have two good answers to the original question. I suggest you select one as the accepted answer and then start a new question for each individual error that you can't resolve yourself.

Comment: I can't accept an answer until one actually solves the problem. Until then I'll keep plugging away. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just create solution and then press right button: Add -> Existing web site...

You can debug using development web server in VS.

[image]

Comment: There is no "Add > Existing web site."

Comment: @EscobarCeaser - This is on the FILE menu (although it may not be in visual studio express/visual web developer)

Comment: Thanks. Still doesn't even come close to working. I get hundreds of errors.

Comment: @EscobarCeaser, do you have VS 2010? I added picture.

Comment: Yes I actually think the site targets framework 2.0. What does that mean for me?

Comment: you can press right button on web site and change targeting framework.

Comment: Thanks. Still no good. There are far too many problems to be fixed by simply clicking add existing website :)

Answer (score 1):

I think they probably forgot to check in the *.sln* file. If you can't find it, you might be able to add the pages to a new web application or web site.

There are some reasons you might want to keep it as a web site instead of a web application. For instance, a web site allows you to have VB.NET and C# in a single project. There is [some info on the pros and cons on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx).

There are some guidelines on converting a web site to a web application. Although this is not your situation, the information might be useful if you're trying to get your head around which you need. There is a [walkthrough on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx)